# Amazon Storage ec2 direct access like S3

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon, got confused about Amazon ec2, Got few queries I am unable to find on google
Q: Is possible we can directly store images ( by SDK provided by amazon like S3 not by consuming rest api's )
Q: Is ec2 purely for backened services only

I have checked the android aws, they have sdk for ec2, but I am unable to figure it out, how to use to directly access ec2 instance and do some storage stuff.

SDK Link

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android

<strike>The reason I am not using s3 is, S3 storage is not available in Africa Region, kind of must requirement, suggestions will be appreciated.</strike>

The s3 is available  to Africa regions, Check below the comment, I have included the link which enlists all the supported regions

Comment: Are you saying that they have EC2, but not S3 in Africa?  If you just want cloud storage, then maybe consider Onedrive?

Comment: S3 is available in Africa. Thus, its not clear what do you mean by "S3 storage server is not available in Africa"? What "server"?

Comment: I am unable to select  Africa (Cape town) region it seems all regions disabled, The selected region is Global in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help, at last I found the documentation which supports all regions for amazon s3 which is
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html

Rest is simple

```
        val amazonS3Client = getAmazonS3Client()
        var uploadObserver = TransferUtility.builder()
            .defaultBucket("enter_your_s3_bucket_name")
            .context(ApplicationCOntext)
            .s3Client(amazonS3Client).build()

        uploadObserver.upload("enter_your_s3_bucket_name",
            "" + "fileName" + ".mp4",
            File(""),
            CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead).setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {
            override fun onStateChanged(id: Int, state: TransferState?) {
                if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                    success.invoke()
                }

            }

            override fun onProgressChanged(id: Int, bytesCurrent: Long, bytesTotal: Long) {
            }

            override fun onError(id: Int, ex: Exception?) {
                exception?.invoke(ex!!)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 is NOT a server and is just an `Object store`. Sort of like a hardware where you can store 1 file at a time. You can use S3 to save any type of files (non extendable ones). EC2 is just a server / machine which can be used for anything you like it be.

If you just want to save files on S3 using Android SDK then you can do so. Check the `DownloadTask` and `Transfer*` classes to download / upload files on S3 from Android. Reference to S3 classes in Android SDK is below

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/tree/main/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/s3/transferutility